# Using the test command to create a directory if it doesn't exist

Tags: shell, directory, test

I was just wondering whether or not this script code would properly test for the existence of a dir2, and if it doesn't exist, then to create it. Dir1 already exists.

```
[ ! -d /dir1/dir2  ] && mkdir /dir1/dir2
```

Comment: No - not unless `/dir1/` definitely already exists. Use `mkdir -p /dir1/dir2` and forget the `test`.

Comment: ya, Dir1 already existed, it was the end of the path of my home directory. We had to run it as a test, I didn't get the extra credit for it and was wondering if it was incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: `mkdir -p` will fail as well if `dir2` exists as a file other than a directory - or if permissions forbid you to create dirs for whatever reason. I usually do like `mkdir -p ./target/dir && cd ./target/dir || exit`

Comment: Assuming there exists no issues with permissions,and that dir2 doesn't already exist as a file, my test will work, correct? I can't run to check atm.

Comment: I'm not using mkdir -p. Dir1 already exists, i'm testing to see if dir2 exists as a subdirectory of dir1, and to create it only if it doesn't exist. Why would I need to test for dir1 as well?

Comment: You asked if your command properly tests for the existence of and creates `/dir1/dir2` and I'm just saying that it does not properly do this thing. You do not verify the parent dir's existence but use command syntax that fails to create a child dir of a dir that does not exist. It does not properly test for the existence of or properly create the path you asked about - and that's the long and short of it - sorry. And actually, for the endpoint, `[ ! -e ... ]` is probably better anyway.

Comment: So even if the parent directory, in fact, exists, I still need to test for its existence? sorry, i'm just hung up on that part. Or is what my test doing not verifying the existence of Dir1 and trying to create a subdirectory of Dir1? I thought the test would test for the entire path, not just the existence of Dir1.

Comment: What other information is necessary? I apologize, I forgot to add in that Dir1 exists as it is the end of my home path.

Comment: regarding your edit - it still fails if dir2 exists but is not a directory. you need `[ ! -e ... ]`. And anyway, when writing scripts, you should never start with assumptions - always start with ruling out edge case possibilities and work your way in to saner territory. What is *end of home path*? You mean `/dir1/` is `~`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command can fail if `dir1/dir2` exists but is not a directory. If you want to test whether `dir1/dir2` exists at all, use `-e`

```
[ -e dir1/dir2 ] || mkdir dir1/dir2
```

If you really need `dir1/dir2` to be a directory, and an ordinary file with that name is an error and should be replaced, you can test for that case.

```
[ -e dir1/dir2 ] && [ ! -d dir1/dir2 ] && rm dir1/dir2
[ -d dir1/dir2 ] || mkdir dir1/dir2
```

Comment: I've added some more text explaining when that's appropriate

Comment: dir1/dir2 already exists, it doesn't exist in any other fashion than being a directory. Since this is the case, I should be in good shape? This was asked of me as extra credit is the only reason I'm doing it in this manner. I see that -d option is for "file exists and is a directory" whereas -e option is for "file exists." Why wouldn't -d be a better choice, as it is testing to confirm that it is a directory not only a file? Also, thanx for the additional info, will come in handy in the future! This is my first script, so I apologize for the stubbornness.

Comment: There's no need to test that it's a directory if it's guaranteed to be a directory if it exists.

Comment: And that is the reasoning for using the -e option?

Comment: Yes. You only need to check whether it already exists. You don't need to test whether it's a directory, because you know it will be. Just like you don't need to test whether `dir1` exists, because you know it does.